# iOS In App SMS View Not Showing

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, sms, viewcontroller

I have a fairly simple question and it might be posted else where but I cannot find it.

I am using this code in a switch statement to produce an MessageUI to send a text message.

```
 case 1:
         if([MFMessageComposeViewController canSendText])
         {
             MFMessageComposeViewController *controller = [[MFMessageComposeViewController alloc] init];
             controller.messageComposeDelegate = self;
             controller.body = @"Hello from iOS App!";
             controller.recipients = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"18009998888", nil];
             [self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
         }
 NSLog(@"SMS");
 break;
```

But instead of producing a text message View Controller, I get this view, http://img594.imageshack.us/img594/7624/screenshot20130302at931.png

What am I doing wrong? Am I missing a step in the process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't view `MFMessageComposeViewController` on the simulator. Try it on your device and it should work

The reason why `canSendText` is returning yes is because you have the messages app installed on your Mac